# Global variable for debugging messages in R

Tags: r, debugging

I am writing a package and some of my functions return some logging messages or any other values I use for debugging etc.

I am looking for a way to switch this function globally on or of.
The idea was to create a variable, related to my package like PACKAGENAME_ECHO <- TRUE and to ask within my functions for this variable...

Is this the preferred solution? Or is there maybe a better one, without providing a variable as an argument in every function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend `options`, e.g. the user can switch to debugging mode via

```
options(yourpackagename.debugging_mode = TRUE)
```

and within your package you can request this via

```
getOption("yourpackagename.debugging_mode", default = FALSE)
```

which returns `FALSE` if the debugging mode was not set.

Global variables should be avoided whenever possible (and usually, it is possible!)

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good solution. I will wait with (accept answer) there might come other recommendations, if it is ok for you...